# Python asyncio or multithread for fetching data from different sources?

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await, multiprocessing

I have a Python app that needs to fetch data from 2-3 different sources (SQL Server, MongoDB etc..) and it can be done in parallel, as I simply need all of the data together later, and each request does not rely on the others.

I couldn't figure which is better for this case - threads, processes or async await?

I read that differences are mostly in CPU usage and I/O. But what if I simply wish to make multiple requests simultaneously (and not sequentially)? Of course, no CPU usage here at all.

Comment: use threads if you do not have async libs for the tasks, otherwise use asyncio. There is no need to use multiprocessing module for I/O tasks, so you have only twio choices in Python to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you have a look at python's builtin [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module...

... a quote from the doc:

> CPython implementation detail: In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing or concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor. However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

in short... multithreading has the problem of `GIL` (e.g. global interpreter lock) but as you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock)...

> ...the GIL is always released when doing I/O.